# Loading .RData in R 3.2.2

Tags: r, rdata

I'm missing something very basic here. I want to retrieve saved `.RData` using `load` command but could not figured out it.

```
X <- seq(from=1, 10, by=1)
Y <- seq(from=1, 20, by=2)
df1 <- data.frame(X, Y)
df1

save(object=df1, file = "mdf.RData")
load(file = "mdf.RData")
mdf

Error: object 'mdf' not found

load(file = "mdf.RData", .GlobalEnv)
mdf

Error: object 'mdf' not found
```

Comment: The object you saved was `df1`. That's the object that gets loaded when you run `load(file = "mdf.RData")`. So do `rm(df1); load(file = "mdf.RData"); df1`.

Comment: Another option is `saveRDS` which you can use to just save a single object. `saveRDS(df1, "mdf.rds"); mdf = readRDS("mdf.rds")`. When you do it this way, you can assign the object to a new name when you load it into your workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdf.RData is a file in the hard disk of your computer. The R variable you saved in this file is df1. So after you load(file="mdf.RData"), the R variable df1 will be loaded into R. The right code:

```
load(file = "mdf.RData")
df1
```